# attribute systemNavigationBarIconBrightness doesn't work in flutter 3.16

Tags: flutter

In this code, when I set the value of `systemNavigationBarIconBrightness` to `Brightness.light` or `Brightness.dark`, The icon color of the navigation bar is always white. Can it change to black?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.teal,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ));

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Hello, Flutter!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Screenshots from real android phone.Runing result↓↓↓ (always white)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### I do not think so.

The whole `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` is a little annoying to use. I had problems with this myself.

I do not know if you also develop for iOS, but they have their brightness' switched. So Brightness.light means white, whereas on iOS it means in a light environment, making it black.

I, unfortunately, think they started to auto select the icon color based on the Navigation Bar color, so it looks more clean for users.

Here is my method if it is any help to you:

```
if (isAndroid) {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
  ));
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
} else {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ));
}
```

### Suggestion

Try changing the `Colors.teal` to `Colors.teal[300]`. Making it lighter might change the icon brightness

Comment: I'm not sure is this a bug or not in flutter.Finally I did this use flutter_statusbarcolor ns